# PHP COUNT and skip every other record

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I have asked a similar question earlier but I have narrowed it down and would like to start a new question.

The following script inserts a To and From dates into a DB record.  I want to add the option of skipping every other week. The following is very close however, it skips the first week which I don't want it to do.  Is there a way that I can use the COUNT feature and only use the ODD number records from the Count and insert those?

```
$week_day = date('w', $curr); # 0 - 6 to access the $week array

if ($week[$week_day]) { # skip if nothings in this day

    $date = date('Y-m-d', $curr);
    $sql->query("SELECT COUNT(schedule_id) FROM $pageDB WHERE doctor_id = $doc_id AND schedule_date = '$date'");

    if (!$sql->result(0)) { # skip if this is already defined
        $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 week", $curr));
        $sql->query("INSERT INTO $pageDB (schedule_date, time, doctor_id, location_id) VALUES ('$date', '".$week[$week_day]."', $doc_id, '".$location[$week_day]."')");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a row-number, then use MOD (=> pos % 2) to take the odd or even rows.

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    a.* 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT  
            @row := @row + 1 AS pos, 
            t.* 
        FROM 
            your-TABLE t, 
            (SELECT @row := 0) b
    ) a 
WHERE 
    pos % 2 = 0
```

Comment: The script selects a week. Say the week of August 6th. It chooses all 7 days in the week.

Then I have a form that I can pick the To and From dates to copy the contents of the Selected week.

So, say I want to copy the content of that week into another week.  Say I want to copy the content into the week of January 5, 2014 until February 28th.  That is a total of 8 weeks.  However, I only want to copy the selected week into every other week between January 5, 2014 and February 28th

So it would copy the contents into the week of the Jan 5th then into the week of the Jan 19th etc...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a counter and check if it is even/odd with [`modulus- %`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) - `if($j%2 != 0)`

```
$week_day = date('w', $curr); # 0 - 6 to access the $week array

$j = 1; // counter

if ($week[$week_day]) { # skip if nothings in this day

    $date = date('Y-m-d', $curr);
    $sql->query("SELECT COUNT(schedule_id) FROM $pageDB WHERE doctor_id = $doc_id AND schedule_date = '$date'");

    if ($j%2 != 0) {
        $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 week", $curr));
        $sql->query("INSERT INTO $pageDB (schedule_date, time, doctor_id, location_id) VALUES ('$date', '".$week[$week_day]."', $doc_id, '".$location[$week_day]."')");
         $j++; // increase the counter
    }
}
```